# Лес и бор - что есть что?

Tags: семантика

Нашел на одной карте (в Вики - в статье о  [горе Воздыхательнице](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), [карта Закревского](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0#/media/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Kyev_Zakrvsky_map_01.png))  текст ***"Лес и бор"*** (совсем точно - Лѣсъ и боръ).

Бор это тоже лес - по современным по крайней мере понятиям. Поэтому "лес и бор" звучит странно. То ли бор тут - "не лес", то ли лес - не бор. Карта совсем не древняя, не могли так значения измениться. Видимо, какое-то особое использование. Или это некая фигуры речи? Как "Митрополит Московский и всея Руси"?

Comment: На интуитивном уровне: бор - про хвойные деревья, возможно имелся ввиду смешанный лес? Правда непонятно какое это имеет значения в рамках картографии.

Comment: @yolosora карта, как вы понимаете, историческая, попросту говоря - обычный план. Так что насчет картографии можно не заморачиваться. А вот насчет смешанного леса. Ну да, смешанный. Да вот только никак это не решает проблему, получается, что "бор"  - не лес?!

Comment: Бор, ясное дело, хвойные деревья, поэтому лучше изучить "лес". У Даля мельком упоминание " дубовый лес". Ещё яснее у Фасмера, региональные названия  лиственного леса.

Answer (score 1):

Такое разделение встречается, когда речь идёт об истории города Киева:

> И сотворили градок во имя брата своего старшего и нарекли имя Киев
> (Кыев). И был около них лес и бор великий, и ловили зверя. И были мужи
> мудрые и смышленые, нареклись поляне, и до сего дня по ним же кияне –
> поляне; были же поганые, жертвуя озерам и источникам, и рощам, как
> прочие поганые» . княжеская охота в «лесу и бору
> великом»http://lubovbezusl.ru/publ/istorija/kiev/a/40-1-0-449
>
> «Был вокруг города (Киева) лес и бор велик, и ловили там зверей, а
> были те мужи мудры и смыслены, и назывались они полянами, от них
> поляне и доныне в Киеве».
> https://litportal.ru/avtory/vladimir-borisovich-egorov/read/page/4/kniga-u-istokov-rusi-mezh-varyagom-i-grekom-127857.html

В Большой советской энциклопедии, БСЭ, читаем:

БОР (СОСНОВЫЙ ЛЕС)

> Сосновый лес, произрастающий **преимущественно на сухой песчаной почве**
> (**сосновые леса, произрастающие на избыточно влажных и сырых почвах, на
> сфагновых болотах, Б. не называют)**. В СССР Б. занимают огромные
> площади от тундры до южной границы ареала сосны . Типичные Б. растут
> на дюнных холмистых местах и плато. В них нет подлеска; в живом
> напочвенном покрове преобладают лишайники. Эти леса составляют группу
> сухих Б. - беломошников или лишайниковых и близких к ним типов леса.
> На пологих склонах со свежими песчаными почвами произрастают свежие Б.-
> брусничники, черничники, чистые зеленомошники. В их составе могут встретиться берёза, местами ель и другие породы; в подлеске - единично
> рябина, можжевельник и др.; в живом покрове - брусника, черника,
> зелёные мхи. На более богатых супесчаных и суглинистых почвах
> развиваются сложные Б. двух-, трёхпородного состава (сосна с елью,
> сосна с дубом, сосна с липой и лещиной) с развитым подлеском и хорошо
> выраженным покровом. Такие Б. дают много ценной деловой древесины.

Учёные-лесоводы разделяют леса по типам:

> Издавна леса средней полосы Европейской части России делят на
> краснолесье (хвойные), чернолесье (лиственные) и смешанные, состоящие
> из хвойных и лиственных деревьев. От пород, населяющих различные почвы
> севера, произошли старинные русские наименования разновидностей этих
> лесов: бор, суборь, рамень, согра, красная рамень и т. д.
>
> • Бор — сосновый лес на песчаной, обычно возвышенной или холмистой
> местности;
>
> • рамень — по преимуществу еловый лес на глинистых или суглинистых
> почвах;
>
> • согра — сыроватый сосновый лес с примесью ели, березы и других
> деревьев. Сосновый лес. Сосновые леса, в свою очередь, также имеют
> различные подразделения. Крестьяне издавна приметили:
>
> • Лучшая строевая (кондовая) сосна с прочной, слегка красноватой
> древесиной растет в бору-ягоднике, то-есть в таком сосняке, где понизу
> много ягодных кустарников, особенно черники.
>
> • В согре сосна имеет сбежистый ствол, то-есть быстро утончающийся к
> вершине, и поэтому малопригодный для построек. Эта сосна мяндовая —
> крупнослойная, с недостаточно прочной древесиной.
>
> • Самая смолистая сосна растет в бору-беломошнике, где под деревьями
> много оленьего лишайника, имеющего светлосерую окраску.

Видимо, на той карте отмечен лес вообще и  отдельно большой бор как сухое место, где растёт кондовая сосна и есть ягодники, то есть дело не в том, что "то ли бор тут - "не лес", то ли лес не бор", а в том,что есть **и место для охоты, и лесной массив из  ценных пород сосен и ягодника.**

Comment: Людмила, а вы карту-то видели? Если да, то там все очевидно, а все ваши слова просто избыточны. Кроме, конечно, последнего замечания.

Comment: *На той карте отмечен лес вообще и отдельно большой бор как сухое место* - Ну не совсем так, конечно, никакого "отдельно" там нет. Именно что вместе, одной надписью. Но замечание о сухои месте - это да, я о том думал. Насчет ценных пород и охоты - это ахронизм, какие уж там породы - во времена кн. Ольги?!

Answer (score 0):

По некотором размыщлении пришел к выводу, что под "бором" в древнем Киеве разумели не столько лес, сколько сухое место, где сосны хорошо растут. В этом мы частично сходимся с Людмилой. И второе соображение: на карте есть (выше по Днепру, с другой стороны от самого города) есть аналогичная надпись "лес и болото". То есть противопоставляется  наземная часть ландшафта наДземной.

Похоже, это единственная хоть чем-то подкрепленная версия.